# Move page number and headigns to margin

Tags: header-footer

How can I move page number and headings to the margin using KOMA-Script?

I'm looking for this layout:

[image: layout]

where red circle means position of the page number after the section (or chapter) name.

So far i have following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half, DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, libertine}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includemp,showframe}



\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\blindtext[1]
\marginpar{\blindtext[1]}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the loading order.

Note that `scrpage2` is outdated. Its successor is package **`scrlayer-scrpage`.** This package sets `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` automatically.

[image: rerunnerScrbookHeaderInMargin]

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, libertine}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includemp,showframe}

\usepackage[
  headsepline,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar,
  footwidth=head% if footer and header should have the same width
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% modern version


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\blindtext[1]
\marginpar{\raggedright No Wombat can be found here, please be aware of that}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

---

With outdated package **`scrpage2`** you have to activate the page style `scrheadings` manually.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, libertine}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includemp,showframe}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}
\setfootwidth[0pt]{head}% if footer and header should have the same width
\pagestyle{scrheadings}% <- added

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\blindtext[1]
\marginpar{\raggedright No Wombat can be found here, please be aware of that}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe better `\usepackage[headsepline, headwidth=textwithmarginpar, footwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}`. Commands `\setheadwidth` and `\setfootwidth` are not mentioned in the documentation of `scrlayer-scrpage`.  AFAIK `\setheadwidth` and `\setfootwidth` are defined for compatibility with `scrpage2`. Both commands  are not mentioned in the documentation.  They set only the related KOMA options.

Comment: @esdd I didn't check the manual. But the question is Community-wiki, feel free to improve it :-)